GenerateDepsFile Task Fails: "Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0'"
I'm encountering an error while building any .NET project using Visual Studio 2022 Professional. The build fails with the following error message:
The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
File name: 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.DependencyContextWriter.Write(DependencyContext context, Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateDepsFile.WriteDepsFile(String depsFilePath)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/netstandard.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/netstandard/netstandard.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/netstandard.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/netstandard/netstandard.EXE.


Environment Details
IDE: Visual Studio 2022 Professional 17.12.2
Operating System: Windows 11 (64-bit).
What I Tried

Ensured all NuGet packages were up-to-date.
Verified the project targets .NET 6 (or a compatible framework with netstandard2.1).
Cleaned the solution and deleted the bin and obj folders manually before rebuilding.
Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 Professional completely.
Despite these efforts and scouring the internet for potential solutions, nothing has resolved the issue.

